# Media player that can be told what tracks I want to skip

Tags: software-recommendation, rhythmbox, banshee, music-player, quodlibet

Some tracks in my music library only consist of introductory talk and things like that I usually want to skip.  Is there a media player that can be taught to not play certain tracks, either using ID3 tags or a blacklist?  I looked at Rhythmbox, Banshee and Quod Libet but so far didn't discover a  built-in feature or extension like that.

Comment: If nothing like this exists, I might consider writing a Quod Libet plugin of my own, which seems reasonably simply.

Comment: Why not just create a playlist of the tracks you want to play...

Comment: Too lazy ;-).  And I'd constantly have to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gmusicbrowser for that. It includes powerful filtering options which allow you to add filters (or intelligent playlists, as other players call it) such as "Comment does not include '[SKIP]'", "Rating >= 50%" or "Rating set to default".

When creating your filter rule, be aware that comments are saved in the file metadata while ratings are saved in gmusicbrowser's settings file ;)

Comment: Heißer Scheiß! So, a filter seems to auto-create a playlist from all the available tracks. But can I also apply filters to individual albums or the current queue?

Comment: Yes, that's no problem either. I don't know which version and look of gmusicbrowser you are using, but for me, it is just selecting an artist from the first of the three top columns [, then clicking an album] and afterwards selecting the filter. With the little play button between the three top columns and the track list below, the filtered tracks are all copied to the playlist. I'll make a screenshot so it's clearer.

Comment: Here it is: http://tinypic.com/r/24pe9ds/8

Comment: Indeed, worked! I changed the layout to "Lists, Library & Context" and all needed UI elements were visible. I'll have to experiment with layouts little further.